# Test running DevStack on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualbox, openstack

I am new to the OpenStack technologies so, in order to get familiarized, for the last two days I am trying to test run the DevStack single node installation on a 16.04 Ubuntu Server virtual machine on VirtualBox. Currently the local.conf file looks something like this:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=<password>
DATABASE_PASSWORD=<password>
RABBIT_PASSWORD=<password>
SERVICE_PASSWORD=<password>
HOST_IP=192.168.1.6 <--- (Server VM is Bridged so I get this address)
#HOST_IPV6=2001:db8::7
LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log
LOGDAYS=2
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.1.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=enp0s3
```

But every time I try to run stack.sh, the execution exits and I get this output on the shell screen:

```
2017-01-28 10:47:37.791 | No matching distribution found for hacking<0.13,>=0.12.0 (from -r /opt/stack/tempest/test-requirements.txt (line 4))
2017-01-28 10:47:38.006 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
2017-01-28 10:47:38.017 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  local r=1
2017-01-28 10:47:38.031 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs -p
2017-01-28 10:47:38.056 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  jobs=
2017-01-28 10:47:38.070 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  [[ -n '' ]]
2017-01-28 10:47:38.082 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  kill_spinner
2017-01-28 10:47:38.097 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:383               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2017-01-28 10:47:38.109 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:499                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2017-01-28 10:47:38.123 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:500                  echo 'Error on exit'
2017-01-28 10:47:38.123 | Error on exit
2017-01-28 10:47:38.135 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  generate-subunit 1485599019 1439 fail
2017-01-28 10:47:39.459 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:502                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2017-01-28 10:47:39.489 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:505                  /home/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2017-01-28 10:47:40.630 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  exit 1
```

Any thoughts on what might be the case for this problem? And for that matter, can anyone suggest a guide I can use for DevStack that works with current ubuntu and devstack distributions? (I am aware of the OpenStack guide from 2014, but it doesn't seem to work anymore).

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

#### For Database:-

```
###localrc
HOST_IP=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PASSWORD=nova
RABBIT_PASSWORD=nova
SERVICE_TOKEN=nova
SERVICE_PASSWORD=nova
ADMIN_PASSWORD=nova
SWIFT_HASH=nova
```

#### Enable Swift and Disable Swift:-

```
###Enable Swift
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account

###Disable Swift
disable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account
```

#### Enable and Disable neutron:-

```
###Enable Neutron
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service q-metering

###Disable Neutron
enable_service n-net
disable_service q-svc
disable_service q-agt
disable_service q-dhcp
disable_service q-l3
disable_service q-meta
disable_service q-metering
```

#### Enable and Disable Heat:

```
###Enable Heat
enable_service heat h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw h-eng

###Disable Heat
disable_service heat h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw h-eng
```

---

After making `localrc` in cd devstack run command
`FORCE=yes ./stack.sh`